# Dockerfile COPY {source:-...}

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

When you create a project in Visual Studio 2017 with Docker support, the Dockerfile has the following line:

```
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

What does it mean? Where does the source macro point to? What is the meaning of the dash?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is called *variable substitution*.

In English, it translates to this:
*"Hey Docker, when you build this, `COPY` the path you find the in `$source` variable in to the current directory in the image (`.`). If `$source` is empty or absent, just use the default path `obj/Docker/publish`"*

`$source` is an environment variable that is defined before executing `docker build`.

***Some references:***

- [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution)
- [Bash variable substitutions](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

Comment: When I tried to build from command line I ran into this issue: `lstat obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory`. I copied the command from VS build window so the command itself should be correct.

Comment: It didn't work from the command line because the `source` variable is passed by Visual Studio at build time.

Comment: @Hasan you are a life saver :)

Comment: This works fine for me in visual studio but the `publish` part of the path doesn't exist so I'm confused about how this actually works. Can anyone share some insight with this?

Comment: If you look at `Container Tools` output you can see `--build-arg "source=obj\Docker\empty"` so it looks like what is in the docker file is fallback.

Comment: What is so confusing about this is that the compose overrides change the behavior of "COPY"; e.g. docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yaml specifies that you source is going into C:\inetpub\wwwroot regardless of what your WORKDIR is set to in your Dockerfile. I'm a newb to container tools and docker-compose, but the fact that the "." in COPY ${source} . is different than what you set WORKDIR to is very unobvious for me

Comment: @MikeFrank, Visual Studio for Debug configuration sets the "source" variable to  "obj\Docker\empty" (an empty folder) that overwrites a default value, then mounts the project root to the container in "docker run" so that in Debug the container works with your actual project files in your actual file system.

The default "obj/Docker/publish" value is intended for Release/prod configuration: to build a release you suppose to publish your project in "obj/Docker/publish" folder and then run "docker build".

Comment: It looks to me like in debug mode intepub\wwwroot is mapped via a volume to your actual source directory on the host (passes \empty). But when you publish, it probably copies the actual files into the container (slower).